# Stack level too deep with ruby

Tags: ruby

I am not doing anything fancy here; nothing. As a noob, could someone explain to me why this is happening? I am following [this tutorial](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) and I got the error:

**Rails Console:**

```
require 'bigdecimal' #=> false

sum = BigDecimal.new("0") #=> stack level too deep
```

So I thought, let me install [BigDecimal](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal) and all would be ok. No. Same issue. Is this an issue with `ruby 2.3.1p112`? Does it has any affiliation with Rails 5 that Im using? Im in the console, not Rails. Thanks.

Stack Trace:

```
irb(main):001:0> BigDecimal.new("2.11")
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/big_decimal_to_s.rb:4:in `to_s_with_default_format'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb:9:in `to_s'
... 10876 levels...
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sylar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: You always get `false` when you `require 'bigdecimal'`?

Comment: It's the first Im requiring it so I dont know if I should see either true or false. But now, it's always false.

Comment: Not getting this error. Tried `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]` and `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`. Are you **sure** that this is the line causing the error?

Comment: @maxpleaner To confirm, a gem in my gemfile is causing this so it's not ruby issue at all. Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not a ruby issue if it's a gem. But if you got it sorted out I'm glad

Comment: @maxpleaner Not as yet. I have a rails 4 project without the issue, with same gems as in rails 5 so I'm digging around. I'll update when I've found something.

Comment: You can show the stack trace here if you need more help.

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks. I've updated post.

Comment: @Sylar have you run `bundle update xeroizer`? Seems like there is a [related issue](https://github.com/waynerobinson/xeroizer/pull/301) which was recently resolved

Comment: Yes I did. At first I thought it was xeriozer so I went ahead and install a rails 4 project with same gems. Rails 4 rails console, BigDecimal works great. Maybe xeroizer not compatible with rails 5. I have not yet tried another rails 5 project without xeroizer. 99.99% says it's xeroizer with rails 5.

Comment: @maxpleaner Got it! In gemfile under group development, I have `gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'` uninstalled that and all is well. Know of a fix?

Comment: @Sylar don't know. Personally I'm a big fan of awesome print but it does do some core patches, [see here](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print/tree/master/lib/awesome_print/core_ext)

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig around why I get this error. Thanks for the support.